# Need help fudging a group in 8039

Tags: building, technic

So, I'm building "8039 Venator-class Republic Attack Cruiser ™ Star Wars TM" and I've hit a snag.

I need help fudging the instruction from page 76 of book 1 for that set (see picture below).

I'm out of piece number 4158830 and the variant (Technic Cross-block 2x1) that is one brick shorter.  I also tried the 2x2 Cross Block Fork but that splits the L-beams.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might not be ideal, but have you tried replacing each Crossblock 2x3 with a Crossblock 90 and a Technic Lever 2M?

[image: Crossblock 90 prototype]

You lose a little bit of stability on the bottom edge with only two pin connections instead of four, but I think it'll do the job just fine. The new parts list is then:
 2x Crossblock 90 Deg
 2x Technic Angle Beam 4x2 90 Deg
 2x Technic Lever 2M
 1x Cross Axle 3M
 1x Cross Axle 5M

Comment: Thanks for the idea Nathan.  I really need it to help stabilize the connection between the "front" and "back" sections.

Comment: Even losing those two pin connections should give you enough stability to tie the front and back together based on the rest of the instructions I was looking at. It's worth a try anyway. Besides, in the worst case there is always BrickLink, right?

Comment: Implemented and worked brilliantly!